# Magnolia not starting on Vanilla Tomcat Server

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, magnolia

So, I think this might be a trivial problem but am currently at a loss.

I created a vanilla Tomcat server on Ubuntu (`tomcat-10.0.4`).

It is configured to run on `port 80` and I can see the Tomcat Manager fine.

Java has been installed

```sh
apt install default-jdk -y
```

Tomcat runs under its own user (`tomcat`) with full rights to its installation folder (`/opt/tomcat`)

```sh
chown tomcat: -R /opt/tomcat/
```

Magnolia was downloaded (`magnolia-dx-core-demo-webapp-6.2.6.war`)

The war file was renamed to `magnoliaAuthor.war` and the tomcat user made the owner of the file.

When moved to the webapps folder the war file is automatically extracted.

The `ls -li` command yields:

```
1283171 drwxr-x---  6 tomcat tomcat      4096 Mar 29 15:12 magnoliaAuthor
 256320 -rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat 486185464 Jan 27 17:37 magnoliaAuthor.war
```

So far so good. But in the Tomcat Web Application Manager I see the application is not running. I click `Start` and the application fails to start with only the following message:

`FAIL - Application at context path [/magnoliaAuthor] could not be started`

The logs are not helpful.

manager.*.log

```
29-Mar-2021 18:30:07.589 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/magnoliaAuthor'
29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.016 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

localhost_access_log.*.txt

```
[29/Mar/2021:18:29:59 +0000] "GET /magnoliaAuthor/ HTTP/1.1" 404 770
tomcat [29/Mar/2021:18:30:17 +0000] "POST /manager/html/start?path=/magnoliaAuthor&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=A78549F3B45386757080EA3D1CDBDD4A HTTP/1.1" 200 17747
```

localhost.*.log

```
29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.278 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener]
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
                at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
...
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
                ... 38 more
29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.278 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.007 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener]
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
...
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
                ... 46 more
29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.007 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

catalina.out

```
29-Mar-2021 18:29:31.155 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/magnoliaAuthor.war]
29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.275 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list$29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.278 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.278 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/magnoliaAuthor] startup failed due to previous errors
29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.287 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/magnoliaAuthor.war] has finished in [12,132] ms         29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.004 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete lis$29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.007 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.009 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/magnoliaAuthor] startup failed due to previous errors
```

catalina.*.log

```
29-Mar-2021 18:29:31.155 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/magnoliaAuthor.war]                                         29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.275 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list$29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.278 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.278 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/magnoliaAuthor] startup failed due to previous errors                                            29-Mar-2021 18:29:43.287 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/magnoliaAuthor.war] has finished in [12,132] ms
29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.004 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete lis$29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.007 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-Mar-2021 18:30:17.009 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/magnoliaAuthor] startup failed due to previous errors
```

With the above information I don't see anything to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, Magnolia is currently not compatible with Jakarta EE 9. You can follow progress on that issue at [MAGNOLIA-8041](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-8041)

Comment: As a workaround one might use the [Tomcat Migration Tool for Jakarta EE](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi)